How can I convert protobuff "map" type to object?
I have a next proto type:
message Test {
    map <string, string> values = 1;
}


Next, I'm making an object of this type:
const test = new Test().getValuesMap().set("test", "1")

And then, I'm trying to lead this type to an object:
console.log(JSON.stringify(test.toObject(), null, 4));

So, I'm getting this structure:
{
    valuesMap: [
        ["test", "1"]
    ]
}

But I'm expecting a structure like this:
{
    values: {
        test: "1"
    }
}

According to this file, the behaviour with "valuesMap" is valid. However, is there any way to convert a proto to an object as I'm expecting?
Also, the provided example is synthetic. In real case I have a recursive structure like this:
{
    "root": {
        "valuesMap": [
            [
                "key1",
                {
                    "name": "some-name"
                    "nested": {
                        "valuesMap": [
                            [
                                "key2",
                                {
                                    "name": "other-name"
...


So instead of using just res.toObject(), I need to write some recursive function on a client to transform this object.



function convert(obj) {
  function rec(o) {
    o.values = Object.fromEntries(o.valuesMap || []);
    delete o.valuesMap;
    for (const k in o.values) {
      if (o.values[k].nested) {
        rec(o.values[k].nested);
      }
    }
  }
  rec(obj);
}

const data = {
  root: {
    valuesMap: [
      [
        'key1',
        {
          name: 'name-1',
          nested: {
            valuesMap: [
              [
                'key2',
                {
                  name: 'name-2',
                  nested: {
                    valuesMap: [['qq', { a: 1 }]],
                  },
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
};
convert(data.root);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));




Thank you.
There is no problem to write recursion to transform an object. I'm looking for a native way to do this (like res.toObject()).

how about create a class overriding the toObject method,  class BetterTest extends Test { toObject() {...} }
